# Making a certain view tappable in CollectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I want to make certain view in cell of collectionView tappable.

Code Of ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let collectionView:UICollectionView = {
        let view = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        view.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let cv : UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: view)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        cv.isPagingEnabled = true
        return cv
    }()
    
    let arrayData:[Data] = [Data(vectorImages: "Group 3", maskImages: "", rectangleImage: "", headingLabel: "Document Reader", detailText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sit tortor malesuada egestas velit magna. Egestas congue nisi tincidunt urna.",view: View(background: .systemPurple, cornerRadius: 12),labelInView: "Get Started"),
                            Data(vectorImages: "Group 10", maskImages: "Mask group-2", rectangleImage: "Rectangle 144", headingLabel:"Read and View", detailText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sit tortor malesuada egestas velit magna. Egestas congue nisi tincidunt urna.",view:View(background: .systemPurple, cornerRadius: 12),labelInView: "Get Started"),
                            Data(vectorImages: "Group 11", maskImages: "Mask group-3", rectangleImage: "Rectangle 144", headingLabel: "Read and View", detailText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sit tortor malesuada egestas velit magna. Egestas congue nisi tincidunt urna.",view: View(background: .systemPurple, cornerRadius: 12),labelInView: "Get Started"),
                            Data(vectorImages: "Group 12", maskImages: "Mask group-4", rectangleImage: "Rectangle 144", headingLabel: "Read and View", detailText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sit tortor malesuada egestas velit magna. Egestas congue nisi tincidunt urna.",view: View(background: .systemPurple, cornerRadius: 12),labelInView: "Get Started")]
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemPurple
        
        setupView()
        setDelegatesAndDatasource()
        registerCell()
        
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            
        ])
    }
    
    func setDelegatesAndDatasource() {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func registerCell() {
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    
    
}
```

extension ViewController:

```
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource {
 
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.customView.vectorImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(arrayData[indexPath.row].vectorImages)")
        cell.customView.maskImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(arrayData[indexPath.row].maskImages)")
        cell.customView.rectangleView.image = UIImage(named:"\(arrayData[indexPath.row].rectangleImage)")
        cell.customView.heading.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].headingLabel
        cell.customView.detailText.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].detailText
        cell.customView.view = arrayData[indexPath.row].view as! View
        cell.customView.labelInView.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].labelInView
        cell.viewTapped = { [weak self] aCell in
        
        let idx = self?.collectionView.indexPath(for: aCell)
        
        print("bottomView in cell at indexPath: \(idx ?? nil) was tapped")
    }
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 393 , height: 852)
    }
    
}
```

In this cell of CollectioView cell.customView.view this View I want it to make it tappable

Code Of ScreenView that in this a view which I want to make tappable

```
import UIKit

class ScreenView: UIView {
    
    let rectangleView = ImageView(image: "")
    
    let maskImage = ImageView(image: "")
            
    let vectorImage = ImageView(image: "")
    
    let heading = Label(text: "Some Text", font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .black), textColor: .black)
        
    
        let detailText:UILabel = {
            let lbl = UILabel()
            lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            lbl.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .light)
            lbl.numberOfLines = 0
            return lbl
        }()
    
    var view = View(background: .systemPurple, cornerRadius: 12)
    let labelInView = Label(text: "Get Started", font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .black), textColor: .white)
    
    init()
        {
            super.init(frame: .zero)
            self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            setupViews()
        }
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
     func setupViews() {
            
            addSubview(rectangleView)
            rectangleView.addSubview(maskImage)
            rectangleView.addSubview(vectorImage)
            addSubview(heading)
            addSubview(detailText)
            addSubview(view)
            view.addSubview(labelInView)
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                
                rectangleView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
                rectangleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                rectangleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 345),
                rectangleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 441),
                
                maskImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectangleView.topAnchor),
                maskImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 345),
                
                vectorImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectangleView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
                vectorImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectangleView.centerXAnchor),
                vectorImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 313),
                vectorImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 251),
                
                heading.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectangleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
                heading.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                
                detailText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heading.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
                detailText.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                detailText.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 313),
                
                view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailText.bottomAnchor, constant: 74),
                view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectangleView.leadingAnchor ),
                view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 345),
                view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 52),
                
                labelInView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
                labelInView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
            ])
        }
}
```

The Code of CustomCell in CollectionView
import UIKit

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
let customView = ScreenView()

var viewTapped: ((UICollectionViewCell) -> ())?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    tapOnView()
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func tapOnView() {
    
    let tapView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    customView.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapView)
}

func setupView() {
    
        addSubview(customView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        customView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: -140),
        customView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor)

    ])
}

@objc func handleTap() {
    viewTapped?(self)
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look at [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer)

Comment: Your code seems to be mostly UIKIt, but you have things like `View` and `Label` which seem quite SwiftUI-ish. Is it UIKit or some odd hybrid of UIKIt and SwiftUI? (Assuming it's UIKit, set your view's `allowUserInteraction=true`, and attach a UITapGestureRecognizer, as suggested by DonMag.) Note that you need to do some extra work to get the view to highlight on a touch down event like buttons do.

Comment: It is Uikit those are just class of View and Label.

Comment: @DonMag 
 I had added UITapGestureRecognizer but it is not working well. The tap function doesn't works. Where I had to add TapGesture at which class in Cell of CollectionView or ViewController.

Comment: @DuncanC
 I had added UITapGestureRecognizer but it is not working well. The tap function doesn't works. Where I had to add TapGesture at which class in Cell of CollectionView or ViewController.

Comment: Edit your question to show your code that adds the tap gesture recognizer, and provide details needed to understand how that code is used. Also tell us what you mean by "it is not working well." That suggests it works partially.

Comment: @DuncanC 
I had added it Please check it

Comment: @MuhammadKumail - is there a reason you don't want to simply use `didSelectItemAt` ?

Comment: @DuncanC
I had added in extension of ViewController in declaring protocols for CollectionView

Comment: @DonMag 
No there is no reason but how I write code to make the particular View Tappable in didSelectItemAt. It'll be well if you write the code for customView.view

Comment: didSelectItemAt lets you respond to tapping on an entire collection view cell. That's different than attaching a tap gesture recognizer to an individual view in the collection view. Which are you doing?

Comment: In your code it looks like cell.customView is of type ScreenView, and customView.view is a subview of ScreenView of type `View`. Where is your `View` type defined?

Comment: Yeah it is 
View is defined as a separate class.

Comment: @DuncanC Yeah tap didSelectItemAt is for the whole cell. I just want to make a particular view Tappable but it is in that cell where all other imageViews and labels are also defined.

Comment: You are not providing enough detail to make this question answerable.  (Aside from DonMag's very good "let's simplify" answer.) I'm voting to close

Comment: @DuncanC What more do you need I'm providing the full detail

Answer (score 1):

First, a couple Tips for the future...

When posting a question here, make sure your code will run as-is. It is much easier to offer help if we can copy/paste/run without having to **guess** at what the missing code may be.

Also, ***start simple!!!*** Begin with the minimal code necessary to accomplish your goal.

In this case, let's use a cell class with a single subview.

---

**View Controller class** - pretty standard. We'll use an array of colors, which we'll use to set the background of the "custom view" in each cell.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let collectionView:UICollectionView = {
        let view = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        view.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let cv : UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: view)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        cv.isPagingEnabled = true
        return cv
    }()
    
    let arrayData: [UIColor] = [
        .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue, .systemYellow,
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupView()
        setDelegatesAndDatasource()
        registerCell()
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            
        ])
    }
    
    func setDelegatesAndDatasource() {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func registerCell() {
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
}
```

---

**View Controller extension**

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayData.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.customView.backgroundColor = arrayData[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 393 , height: 852)
    }
}
```

---

**Custom Cell class** - with a single `UIView` as a subview, to which we'll add the `UITapGestureRecognizer`. When tapped, we'll print to the debug console, and we'll also "flash" the background color so we see that it responded to the tap.

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let customView = UIView()
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ t: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        print("Got Tap!")
        
        // let's "flash" the customView's background color
        //  so we have a visual indication it was tapped
        let c = customView.backgroundColor
        customView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, animations: {
            self.customView.backgroundColor = c
        })
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
        
        // create and add Tap Gesture Recognizer to customView
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        customView.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        
        customView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // make sure we addSubview to contentView !!
        contentView.addSubview(customView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            customView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400.0),
            customView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: -100),
            customView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit** - another quick example, showing a "bottom view" in the cell that can be tapped. On tap, it will inform the controller via a closure, allowing the controller to do something - in your case, push to a new controller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let collectionView:UICollectionView = {
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        fl.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        let cv : UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        cv.isPagingEnabled = true
        return cv
    }()
    
    let arrayData: [String] = [
        "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth",
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupView()
        setDelegatesAndDatasource()
        registerCell()
    }
    
    // so we can set the cell size when the collection view
    //  has been laid-out
    var currentCVWidth: CGFloat = 0
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        if currentCVWidth != collectionView.frame.width {
            currentCVWidth = collectionView.frame.width
            if let fl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                fl.itemSize = collectionView.frame.size
            }
        }
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            
        ])
    }
    
    func setDelegatesAndDatasource() {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func registerCell() {
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayData.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)as! CollectionViewCell
        
        // set the cell UI elements
        cell.customView.headingLabel.text = arrayData[indexPath.item]
        
        // set the closure so we know when the "bottom view" in a cell was tapped
        cell.gotTapClosure = { [weak self] aCell in
            guard let self = self,
                  let idx = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: aCell)
            else {
                return
            }
            // here is where we would push to another controller on the navigation stack
            //  for now, let's just confirm the cell index
            print("bottomView in cell at indexPath: \(idx) was tapped")
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}


class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // closure
    var gotTapClosure: ((UICollectionViewCell) -> ())?
    
    let customView = ScreenView()
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ t: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        print("Got Tap!")
        
        // call the closure to inform the controller that
        //  the "bottomView" was tapped
        gotTapClosure?(self)
        
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
        
        // create and add Tap Gesture Recognizer to customView.bottomView
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        customView.bottomView.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // make sure we addSubview to contentView !!
        contentView.addSubview(customView)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            customView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
    }
    
}

class ScreenView: UIView {
    
    let headingLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Some Text"
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .black)
        v.textColor = .black
        // so we can see the label frame
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()
    
    let bottomView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemPurple
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return v
    }()
    
    let labelInView: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Get Started"
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .black)
        v.textColor = .white
        // so we can see the label frame
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupViews() {
        
        [headingLabel, bottomView, labelInView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        addSubview(headingLabel)
        addSubview(bottomView)
        bottomView.addSubview(labelInView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            headingLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20),
            headingLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            
            bottomView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 345),
            bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 52),
            bottomView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            
            labelInView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.centerYAnchor),
            labelInView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.centerXAnchor),
            
            bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
        ])
        
        headingLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        labelInView.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        // so we can see this view
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this when running:

[image]

When you scroll to the next cell, the Title label will be updated.

When you tap on the purple "bottomView" - but not the rest of the cell's UI elements - it will call the closure.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, but I want the view which is in customView to be tappable.
Means customView.view by tapping this View we move to SecondController.
Your approach of keeping a separate View works fine but I want customView.view to be tappable.

Comment: @MuhammadKumail - take a little time to understand what that code is doing. You can replace `let customView = UIView()` with something like `let customView = ScreenView()` (there is no reason to be passing all of those init parameters). You should *learn* how it works in this simple example, and then build on that knowledge.

Comment: @MuhammadKumail - it's very confusing to name a UI element `view`, so let's change that to `bottomView` ... then, if you want only the `bottomView` to be tappable, instead of `customView.addGestureRecognizer(t)` use `customView.bottomView.addGestureRecognizer(t)`. How to *"move to SecondController"* is really a separate question. You will want to add a `closure` so the tap on the view in the cell can inform the controller of the tap, and then the controller will push to the next controller.

Comment: @DonMag- I understand it. I was just trying to use view also as init parameter of ScreenView and don't want to initialize separately. Yeah I got your point when I initialize the view separately it easily navigate the view as compare to customView.view. I'm just trying to understand what was issue when we use view in the init, and trying to make the tapGesture.

Comment: @MuhammadKumail - see the **Edit** to my answer. Because you did not provide functional code, I don't know how your cell is really supposed to look. If you study this sample, though, you should be able to understand the necessary concepts.

Comment: @DonMag- Actually as you see the arrayData which is made of Struct. I had changed my code according to your explanation. Could you please check above in CollectionViewCell and View Controller.

Comment: But it is not working in my code Could I upload all the files that you can see it and guide me according too ?

Comment: @MuhammadKumail - if you post your project (somewhere like GitHub) I will take a quick look.

Comment: @DonMag- 
Sure I'll upload my project on GitHub.